# Hooking window creation in an MFC program

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, hook

I want to hook the window creation in an MFC program.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Which method is that (exact name+class name it is member of), and what do you mean by 'listening'?

Comment: When I mean 'listen' I want to keep track of the MFC object instantiations. For example, I would like to keep track of object creation for CWnd class.

Comment: So by 'listening', you mean to hook the procedure `CWnd::Create`? Do you know what [hooking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking) is in Windows?

Comment: Ya I want to hook to the CWnd::Create procedure. I have little idea about hooking. I have gone through the link shared by you. Could you please suggest some ideas on how to hook for CWnd::Create procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SetWindowHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to install a [CBTProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here's some sample code. Just call `InstallHook()` from the beginning of your program, and then monitor the `HCBT_CREATEWND` notification code. You can cancel window creation by returning nonzero from the function, as described in the docs.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MyCbtHook(int nCode,  WPARAM wParam,  LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(nCode)
    {
    case HCBT_CREATEWND:
        {
            HWND hWnd = (HWND)wParam;
            TRACE("A window is being created, HWND = %p\n", hWnd);
            break;
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx( 0, nCode, wParam, lParam );
}

void InstallHook()
{
    SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, MyCbtHook, 0, GetCurrentThreadId());
}
```

Comment: Hi Soham, thanks for quick response. Does the above code, hook to the CWNd::Create procedure globally i.e trace CWnd:Create method calls from outside the application domain?

Comment: No, it does not. However, your question doesn't mention anything about that. Don't you think you should have mentioned that fact **before** I've put effort and time into answering your question? And my username is sashoalm, not Soham.

Comment: Sashoalm, I agree I should have mentioned it in my question. From next time I will try to be more specific.

Comment: OK, can you mark my answer as accepted, because it does answer your question in its current form? Then you can ask a new question, this time with all the details included.

Comment: Sasholam, I am a new user to this forum..Could you please help me in figuring out on how to mark your post as ans?

Comment: There is a green tick-mark below my answer's score, just click on it. Also you can read the [FAQ] before posting your next question.