# Hooking to MFC object creation globally

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a class X inherited from CWnd and I would like to hook to X Create from outside the application domain i.e program A has to monitor X object instantiations in program B. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What is the X Create method? The ctor X:X? Or the window related OnCreate()? Why not use/overload these two functions? Or what exactly do you want to achieve? Are you aware that when subclassing comes into place, your class X will not see the creation of the control but only attach to the already created control?

Comment: What I mean by X Create method is X::Create procedure. I have to hook to the X class instantiations globally.

Comment: Your question is very unspecific and I do not see a difference to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653061/hooking-window-creation-in-an-mfc-program.

Comment: This sounds very familiar: Someone has broken down their problem into two parts: the easy one and the impossible one. You're asking for the impossible one here. Not strictly impossible but certainly not feasible either. I suppose it would help to provide a higher level description of what you are essentially trying to achieve.

Comment: Last attempt before I flag this question to be closed because of being to unspecific: Are we talking only about CWnd? What do you mean with object instantiation? Previously you wrote that you mean CWnd::Create. Is this still true? Or do you now mean creation of an X object, thus a call to X ctor X::X?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't monitor creation of an object of X (X ctor `X::X()`).
2. You also can't monitor calls to `X::Create`.
3. But there might be a solution for you:

Since `X::Create` calls `CWnd::Create` and this creates a window, you can hook up to window creation and might be able to detect when a X's window is created. But you will only be able to recognize this if there is something special about the windows created like a known window class used to create them. If this is the case, then:

You already got the right answer in your previous question [Hooking window creation in an MFC program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653061/hooking-window-creation-in-an-mfc-program).

You can use [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(WH_CBT, lpfn, hMod, dwThreadId) to get notified when windows are created.

Some things to keep in mind:

- The hook function must reside in a DLL, not in the process that calls `SetWindowsHookEx`. This is because windows will load/inject your DLL into every process that it monitors for window creation.
- If you want to monitor 32 bit processes, you need a 32 bit process and DLL.
- If you want to monitor 64 bit processes, you need a 64 bit process and DLL.
- If you want to monitor 32 bit and 64 bit processes, you need a 32 bit and a 64 bit process and DLL.
- Your process must be a windows application, not a console application, and it must keep pumping messages.
- If you know the thread ID, you can pass that to SetWindowsHookEx. If not, you can pass 0 and you will get notified for all windows on the same desktop.
- Be cautious with what you do in the hook function and don't forget to call `CallNextHookEx`.
- You will get notified for different events on different windows and you will have to filter out for nCode==`HCBT_CREATEWND` and the window classes (or whatever) that you are interested in.

Comment: I wanted the hook to the Create procedure from outside the application domain. In the previous post I have not mentioned 'Globally hooking to the Create procedure' as the requirement.

Comment: What do you mean from outside the application domain? Do you want program A to monitor window creation in program B? If so, then this is a total different thing. Please adjust your question to reflect what you really want.

Comment: Ya...Program A has to monitor window creation in Program B. I will update my question.

Comment: @Katie I updated the answer according to your updated question.

Comment: @Katie So what is it? Do you want to monitor _window creation_ or _MFC calls_? You keep changing your mind. It isn't easy to provide help if you change the rules halfway through the game...

Comment: Tim, I am not changing my mind..I initially asked the question on how to GLOBALLY hook to an object creation in MFC. As I have mentioned GLOBALLY word in my question I assumed that people would understand it as hooking to the creation from out of the current application domain also. But as per the thread discussions I understood that the meaning is not conveyed, hence I have updated it

Comment: @Katie You asked how to hook window creation, and then move on to change the requirement to hook object creation instead. What does MFC have to do with this, since you keep repeating this aspect. That's basically what I asked in my previous comment which you still did not address.

Comment: Tim In the current question I asked about 'HOOK to Create procedure fro X class which is inheriting from Cwnd class'. This is the case from the beginning of the current thread. I don't know where does the Window object creation has come. In my previous thread I asked about it but not in the current thread. Please go through the comments and the question again.

Comment: @Katie Your correction reiterates your confusion. You cannot seem to make up your mind. Do you want to hook calls into the Create method or do you want to hook object creation? Those are different things and the answer to either question will be different.

Comment: @Katie What if Program B is not written in MFC? Then you can't hook MFC object creation in a program that doesn't use MFC. And speaking about hooking **globally**, there are sure to be programs not written in MFC in a Windows computer.