# How to change default position of pop-up window in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have an MFC application and I want all pop-up generated by this application as dialog box or using AfxMessageBox should be positioned to some   location given in config file.
Is there a way in MFC to set the default position for any pop-up window ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. If I was going to implement this I would use a hook to detect the showing of dialog-based windows and set their position prior to them being shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily done with a window hook procedure.

Consult this SO post: [Hooking window creation in an MFC program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653061/hooking-window-creation-in-an-mfc-program)

Sample code:

```
static HHOOK g_myHook = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK MyCbtHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (nCode)
    {
        case HCBT_ACTIVATE:
        {
            CWnd* wnd = CWnd::FromHandle((HWND)wParam);
            WINDOWINFO wi;
            wi.cbSize = sizeof(wi);
            wnd->GetWindowInfo(&wi);
            if ((wi.dwStyle & WS_POPUPWINDOW) == WS_POPUPWINDOW)
            {
                wnd->SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

static void InstallHook()
{
    g_myHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, MyCbtHook, 0, GetCurrentThreadId());
}

static void UninstallHook()
{
    if (g_myHook)
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_myHook);
        g_myHook = NULL;
    }
}
```

Call `InstallHook` in the `InitInstance`, then `UninstallHook` in the `ExitInstance` (not required really).

This sample hook procedure moves all popup window to the top left corner.